# Duvidas sobre licenças

Tags: javascript, c#, licença

Todos os programas feitos em "tal" linguagem de programação são livres para se comercializar? e em relação a C# e javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, Junior.

As linguagens relacionadas a Desktop não é necessariamente ter uma licença, mais caso queria comercializar ou até mesmo desenvolver algo para que no futuro seja relacionado como **Seu** ou Até mesmo contendo **direitos autorais** é necessário o licenciamento.

As Linguagens web é preciso bem mais que desktop, pois como muitos **Desenvolvedores Front-End** sabe para ter um certo controle de seu código fonte exposto na internet é necessário uma validação e um licença para que no futuro não aja conflitos com uns (Safados que roube seu código-fonte, fruto de muita determinação) **plágio mosaico**, que no caso é crime, e caso seja necessário ou feito pelo desenvolvedor do código, comprovar que ele é seu, terá em mãos a Licença.

A validação é para apenas comprovar que aquele código-fonte de uma determinada linguagem funciona.

**Para Validar um código de Desenvolvimento Web:**

1. [HTML, XHTML, XML, CSS, PHP ou qualquer outra Relacionada ***W3C***](http://validator.w3.org/)
2. [Validar Codigo JavaScript](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php)
3. [Validar jQuery](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/validacao-de-formularios-com-jquery/onclick=)

**Licenciar código-fonte:**

1. **[Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/choose/)**

**ABS:** Caso queira saber como o [Licenciamento funciona](http://creativecommons.org/licenses), Existe também para linguagens desktop e até mesmo Mobile, tanto licenciamento como Validação, Abraço :)

Answer (score 1):

A licença do software em nada tem a ver com a linguagem de programação utilizada para construí-lo.
Aquele que o constrói é quem decide qual licença aplicar. Há exceções a esta regra, mas de maneira geral é assim que funciona.
Veja alguns exemplos de licença: [Software livre, freeware, shareware, copyleft: entenda as licenças de software](http://tecnologia.uol.com.br/ultnot/2007/12/20/ult4213u266.jhtm)

Dentro das licenças opensource (software livre), ainda há um [subconjunto de tipos de licença](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_de_software_livre), comumente utilizadas no mundo opensource.